# how to delete a single row from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete a single row from table. But when I run the query it deletes all row. Can anyone can help me on this? Here is my code below :

```
DELETE FROM table_name
```

Comment: Which row do you want to delete?

Comment: add a where clause to delete a specific row. ex: delete from table_name where id=1

Comment: Be careful, if '*' added then your all record will gone !!

Comment: @JanDvorak: Nothing wrong with this question.  I would (and did) upvote this just to undo the wanton downvotes.

Comment: @Andomar the asker should specify which row he wants to delete. I don't think he wants to delete exactly one row no matter what (if he does, my downvote is unwarranted). Also, it doesn't show much research effort.

Comment: @Andomar if he does want to remove exactly one row no matter what, all those answers that say "just add a where clause" should be downvoted.

Comment: @Andomar given what answer was accepted, it seems that the question was indeed asked ambiguously. Keeping my downvote.

Answer (score 5):

```
DELETE FROM table_name LIMIT 1
```

here's the basic syntax of `DELETE` in MySQL

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

- [MySQL DELETE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

or you can also do this for a specific ID

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE ID = 'X'
LIMIT 1
```

---

If you don't specify `LIMIT`, it will delete all records that matches with the condition.

<strike>**BUT** there is an exception, you can omit `LIMIT` if you are filtering via a `UNIQUE` column.</strike>

Comment: +1 But I'd remove the last sentence.  A `where UniqueColumn like '%abc%'` filter could still remove multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `WHERE` clause to delete specific row....Your WHERE clause can be like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE <where_clause_condition>
```

You can limit deleting of row by using LIMIT.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE <where_clause_condition> LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to say, which specific row.

use `WHERE`

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE Column = 'Value'
```

Comment: this doesn't guarantee exactly (or at most) one row will be removed

Answer (score 0):

for example your table has field id, or whatever that indicates which row you want to delete.

```
DELETE FROM table_name  WHERE id='some_value'
```

some_value can be an unique identifier  for specific row

Comment: this doesn't guarantee exactly one row will be removed

Answer (score 0):

to delete single row from database you will be required to use the where clause.
in where clause you can provide the unique value / primary key of the record which you will reuqired to delete

```
delete from table_name WHERE id = $id
```

Or you can add the limit to delete query

```
delete from table_name LIMIT 1
```